# ExtJS displaying field name inside chart

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

Consider the following [example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example/charts/StackedBar.html) of a stacked bar chart. I can display the count of each of the fields (comedy, action, drama, thriller) in the bars by adding the label config in the series, but how would I also display the field name?. The renderer config property for label doesn't seem to be of much use as the function only receives the count as argument.

```
label:{
  display:'insideStart'  ,
  field:[null, null, 'drama', 'thriller'],
  renderer:function(item){
    //For this case, item will be an int value. Thus, not sure how useful it is 
    //as we cannot get the field name from it.
  }          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the renderer function is passed [a lot more arguments](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.chart.Label-cfg-label) than just the value. These arguments are the same as the [`onPlaceLabel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.chart.Label-method-onPlaceLabel) method, with the value added to the beginning, and they are better documented there.

We've got the `index` of the field in the series and, as a matter of fact, we have the `series` also available in the `item` argument. With that, we can achieve what you want:

```
label: {
    display:'insideStart'
    ,field:[null, null, 'drama', 'thriller']
    ,renderer: function(value, label, storeItem, item, i, display, animate, index) {
        var series = item.series,
            titles = series.title;
        return titles && titles[index] || series.yField[index];
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the title first because, in real life, I wouldn't display a raw field name to the user. For the record, here's how the whole serie would be configured in order to do that. It doesn't appear in the doc, except for a user comment...

```
series: [{
    type: 'bar',
    axis: 'bottom',
    gutter: 80,
    xField: 'year',
    yField: ['comedy', 'action', 'drama', 'thriller'],
    title: ['Comédie', 'Action', 'Drame', 'Thriller'],
    stacked: true,
    label: {
        display:'insideStart'
        ,field:[null, null, 'drama', 'thriller']
        ,renderer: function(value, label, storeItem, item, i, display, animate, index) {
            var series = item.series,
                titles = series.title;
            return titles && titles[index] || item.yField;
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: All of the parameters except for value are undefined in the renderer function.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Ext4.2 ?